# Generated Button appears in wrong window

Tags: python, tkinter

I started to learn Python and I got a problem that is not discussed in any of the tutorials I've found.

Basically when the program got more complicated I've lost the ability to control where the new elements are appearing. It's difficult to explain it for me since English is not my native language so i made a mock-up program that shows what is wrong with my main program.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk as ttk

clutter=['1PLACEHOLDER', '2PLACEHOLDER', '3PLACEHOLDER', 'PICK ME']

class GRAPHIC_INTERFACE(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args)
        self.grid()
        self.first_window()

    def first_window(self):
        self.button1=tk.Button(self, text="PLACEHOLDER")
        self.button1.grid()
        self.button2=tk.Button(self, text="CLICK ME", command=self.second_window)
        self.button2.grid()
        self.button3=tk.Button(self, text="PLACEHOLDER")
        self.button3.grid()
        #the additional button apears here

    def second_window(self):
        alpha=tk.Toplevel(self)
        self.button4=tk.Button(alpha, text="PLACEHOLDER")
        self.button4.grid()
        self.button5=tk.Button(alpha, text="CLICK ME", command= self.third_window)
        self.button5.grid()

    def third_window(self):
        beta=tk.Toplevel(self)
        self.BOXXY=ttk.Combobox(beta, values= clutter, state='readonly')
        self.BOXXY.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.misplaced_button)     #after choosing the third option an aditional button is created
        self.BOXXY.current(0)
        self.BOXXY.grid()
        self.button6=tk.Button(beta, text="PLACEHOLDER")
        self.button6.grid()
        #the additional button needs to appear here

    def misplaced_button(self, *args):
        Catie=self.BOXXY.get()
        if Catie=='PICK ME':
            self.button7=tk.Button(self, text="I am that problematic button")#this button needs to be in the third window
            self.button7.grid()
        else:
            print "that was not the chosen one"

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Mockup")
root.geometry("180x200")
app=GRAPHIC_INTERFACE(root)
root.mainloop()
```

At first I was thinking that i can control the placement of the widgets by giving them names (i.e alpha, beta) but apparently I was wrong.

Comment: What are we supposed to do when the program runs in order to see this problem?

Comment: "CLICK ME" on the 1 window, "CLICK ME" on the new window, and after selecting the last option on the commbobox in the third window the wrongly placed button will apear in the first window. and thats the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `self.button7` is supposed to be in the third window, all you have to do is use the third window as the parent of the button.

You can accomplish this many ways: you can save the window as an attribute,  you can pass the window in when calling the function, or you can compute the window based on which widow caught the event.

Here's a solution that puts the button in the toplevel that got the event:

```
def misplaced_button(self, event):
    ...
        toplevel = event.widget.winfo_toplevel()
        self.button7=tk.Button(toplevel,...)
    ...
```